# What is a dilating function?

Tags: real-analysis

i have this question:

When i was reading an article i found this word (dilating function)

can someone explain to me what is a dilating function

thanks for any answer

Answer (score 1):

If i transcribe it well in my langage ( fonction dilatante ), that's a function that satisfies
$$\left\|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right\|>\left\|x-y\right\|$$
where $k \geq 1$.

Comment: merci pour la réponse mais c est pas plutot l inverse http://www.bibmath.net/dico/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=./d/dilatante.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, dilation means "rescaling" or "stretching". You scale dimensions by a factor $f$ by replacing $x \to x/f$ in related equations. But a link to the actual article would be good to understand the context precisely.